# Run code when the NSWindow is closed using isReleasedWhenClosed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, nswindow

I'm building a cocoa application, I created a nswindow programatically and I use the `isReleasedWhenClosed` to `false`. When I do that, I do not get alerts of the `func windowWillClose`. I want to know how I can execute code when the user closes the window in isReleasedWhenClosed

Answer (score 1):

`isReleasedWhenClosed` will have no affect on *how* the window is closed, it literally only changes whether the window has a release call sent to it or not, for teardown if nothing else references it.

If your `windowWillClose` notification is not being fired on your properly setup delegate, then the window isn't technically being closed. If the window is simply being "ordered out", that's not technically the same as "closing" according to the API.

Comment: Is there any API where I can call code when the window is ordered out?

Comment: There's no standard notification for that no, but a window is only ordered out ("hidden") if you do explicitly tell it to, so you have control of when it happens. If your window is being closed by the user as you suggested, then it will be *closed*, not ordered out and thus the close notification is what you'd use.